# Class Extension Java

Tags: java, extend

I have class A, and class B ( extends A ). I'm attempting to call out methods from class B, when B is cast as A. Is this possible?

Ex.

```
A myObject = new B();
myObject.myMethodFoundInB(param);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by casting back to B, ie:

```
A myObject = new B();
((B)myObject).myMethodFoundInB(param);
```

or, more safely:

```
A myObject = new B();
if (myObject instanceof B) {
    ((B)myObject).myMethodFoundInB(param);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the method is not defined in parent then you wouldn't be able to call it using the parent class reference.

You may just define an abstract method `myMethodFoundInB` in your parent class and override in your child class. Then you will be able to call `myMethodFoundInB` using parent class reference as well.

Answer (score -1):

This is only possible if "myMethodFoundInB" is declared in class A, which I'm guessing it isnt.

Comment: Can the down voter please help me understand why this answer is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Good point. I was answering only to the given code snippet, but as the post states that is only an example. Thanks